# PHP - Echo is not displaying correctly

Tags: php

https://pastebin.com/pEg8ZARP

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Future Value</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php # Script 1.8 - futureValue.php.
// Set the variables:
$interest = .08;
$amount = 1000;
$years = 20;

// Calculate the value:
$value = $amount* pow( (1+$interest), $years);

// Format the total:
$value = number_format ($value, 2);

// Print the results:
echo "<p>The future value is <b>/$$value</b>.</p>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried pasting it here but the formatting got messed up.

Whenever I try to load the page it just says " The future value is /$$value.
"; ?> " instead of displaying "The future value is $4660.96.".

I am totally lost at what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Use "\" to escape a string. But you could always do "Value is $".$value

Comment: This question will be closed as an Offtopic: typo.  Turn your slash around.

Comment: use single quotes in place of double quotes to encapsulate string.

Comment: `echo "<p>The future value is <b>$$value</b>.</p>";` should also work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo "<p>The future value is <b>$".$value."</b>.</p>";
```

**$** is a special character so you need to [escape](http://phppot.com/php/php-escape-sequences/) it. Or you can always just [concat](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) your string and variable to avoid this problem.

Comment: I have even tried removing $ and tried concatting my string and variable (should have mentioned that before) and I still get the same issue. I have even tried echoing just $value by itself and it still doesn't work right. Could this be a problem on my end?

Comment: try setting your `$value` to a static value instead for now. `$value = 3` and see if it works. Also, comment out `// Calculate the value:
$value = $amount* pow( (1+$interest), $years);

// Format the total:
$value = number_format ($value, 2);`

Comment: Also, tried your PHP code here: http://phptester.net/ and it works if I use my code above or just simply changed the escape to `\\`